ml.net LoadFromEnumerable always give System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
I'm getting the following exception:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Could not determine an IDataView type and registered custom types for member ValueType (Parameter 'rawType')

For those 2 cases:
Case 1 : (could be normal to me to get the exception here):
MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();
var dataViewDateTimeValues = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(dateTimeValues.Data.Values);

Case 2 : exception either here? Why and how to solve it? (does not like 'ValueType' where is not in the schema here) :
MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();
var dataViewDateTimeValues = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(dateTimeValues.Data.Values);
var builder = new DataViewSchema.Builder();
builder.AddColumn("DateTimeOffset", Microsoft.ML.Data.DateTimeOffsetDataViewType.Instance);
builder.AddColumn("Value", Microsoft.ML.Data.NumberDataViewType.Single);
DataViewSchema schema = builder.ToSchema();

For my class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;
using System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335;

namespace CommanDER.Forecast
{
    public class DateTimeValue : ObservableObject
    {
        public DateTimeValue()
        {
            DateTimeOffset = default;
            Value = 0;
        }

        public DateTimeValue(DateTimeOffset dateTime, float value)
        {
            DateTimeOffset = dateTime;
            Value = value;
        }

        public DateTimeValue(DateTimeOffset dateTime, double value)
        {
            DateTimeOffset = dateTime;
            ValueDouble = value;
        }

        public const string DateTimeValueFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";

        [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
        [Browsable(false)]
        [LoadColumn(0)] // EO: For ML.net, for file usage in CSV or TSV (tab separarted value)
        public DateTimeOffset DateTimeOffset { get; set; }

        [LoadColumn(1)] // EO: for file usage in CSV ot TSV (tab separarted value) (used also in ml.net ???)
        public float Value { get; set; }  // Float seems to be required by ml.net

        public double ValueDouble { get => Value; set => Value = (float)value; }

        private double[]? _mlPrediction;

        [VectorType(7)]
        public double[]? MlPrediction { get => _mlPrediction; set => SetProperty(ref _mlPrediction, value); } //  = new double[TotalGuessOfCount];

        public string MlPredictionDisplay
        {
            get => MlPrediction is null ? "{null}" : string.Join(", ", MlPrediction);
        }

        private ValueTypeEnum _valueType = ValueTypeEnum.Raw;

        [Browsable(false)]
        public ValueTypeEnum ValueType { get => _valueType; set => SetProperty(ref _valueType, value); }


        private DateTimeOffset _dateTimeValueCopied = default;

        [Browsable(false)]
        public DateTimeOffset DateTimeValueCopied { get => _dateTimeValueCopied; set => SetProperty(ref _dateTimeValueCopied, value); } // Usually not used otherwise should be a multiple of 7 at same time in order to get same day of week.


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Date: {DateTimeOffset.ToString(DateTimeValueFormat)}, Value: {Value}";
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CommanDER.Forecast
{
    public enum ValueTypeEnum

    {
        Raw = 0,
        Interpolated = 1,
        CopiedFromAnotherDateTime = 2, 
        OutOfRange = 3,
    }
}


I just found a workaround but it implies class modification which it seems to be a bad way to fix this issue. I shouldn't have to modify my class in order to use the ml.net loader: 'LoadFromEnumerable'
My solution is to add an interface to my class containing only the properties I'd like to be used by ml.net.
Code:
public interface ISimpleDateTimeValue
{
    public DateTimeOffset DateTimeOffset { get; set; }
    public double ValueDouble { get; set; }  // Float seems to be required by ml.net
}

DateTimeValue.cs:
public class DateTimeValue : ObservableObject, ISimpleDateTimeValue
{
   ...

In DateTimeValues.cs
public IEnumerable<ISimpleDateTimeValue> SimpleValuesEnumerator
{
    get
    {
        return Data.Select(x => x.Value);
    }
}

Using ml.net:
MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();
var dataViewDateTimeValues = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(dateTimeValues.SimpleValuesEnumerator);

